# DNN 2sxc 500 error when editing template specific module

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Recently I made an addition to an existing 2sxc template where I added a new input field. The field was a drop-down selector and after I enabled it I went through and manually updated all of the instances through the Content-Types and Data manager.

After editing all of the instances I noticed my changes are working and the modules are being built successfully however when I try to edit the instance I am now receiving a 500 error and unable to edit the element.

In the past we've made additions to existing modules and have been able to update the content for the different instances without error but for some reason we are now receiving this error. I am unsure if others have experienced this or if anyone has any suggestions for a fix.

My next step is to try replicating the template file and to see if under the same circumstances we experience the same error.

Comment: I've never heard of this before, basically if I understand you correctly, you get the error when opening the edit-dialog. is this correct?  Could you give us some version numbers to go on?

Comment: just for clarification - because you mention replicating the template file - do you have issues editing the template, or the data?

Comment: The issue is with editing the data. The 500 error is showing on this fetch: "/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/eav/contenttype/getfields?appid=2&staticName=3033e078-3f55-4660-a534-62613bc06373" if that provides any insight.

Comment: 2SXC version 9.32.0

Comment: So apparently it's having trouble getting the field names and types for this content-type. Is the type otherwise ok, or does it maybe not have any fields? if it doesn't have fields, then it would be better to specify that this view doesn't have a content-type.